# Select different count from same table

Tags: oracle

I have the table T_LOCATION_DATA on Oracle DB as follows:

```
Person_ID | Location | Role
----------------------------
101         Delhi      Manager
102         Mumbai     Employee
103         Noida      Manager
104         Mumbai     Employee
105         Noida      Employee
106         Delhi      Manager
107         Mumbai     Manager
108         Delhi      Employee
109         Mumbai     Employee
```

Another table is T_STATUS with following data:

```
Person_ID | Status
-------------------
101         Active
102         Active
103         Inactive
104         Active
105         Active
106         Inactive      
107         Active     
108         Active
109         Inactive
```

I am trying to get the count of both Employee and Manager who are Active; group by location in a single query so that the result comes as follows:

```
Location  |   MANAGER COUNT |  EMPLOYEE COUNT
Delhi         1                1
Mumbai        1                1
Noida         0                1
```

I am trying with following query but with no result:

```
select location, count (a.person_id) as MANAGER COUNT, 
                 count (b.person_id) as EMPLOYEE COUNT 
from   T_LOCATION_DATA a,T_LOCATION_DATA b 
where  a.person_id in (select person_id from t_status where status='Active')
```

... and I get lost here

Can someone guide me on this please?

Comment: Mind if I format your SQL so it doesn't have to be scrolled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your data, I would query like this:

```
SELECT 
  Location,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Role='Manager' THEN 1 END) as count_managers,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Role='Employee' THEN 1 END) as count_employees,
  COUNT(*) count_everyone
FROM
  t_location_data l 
  INNER JOIN 
  t_status s
  ON
    l.person_id = s.person_id AND
    s.status = 'Active'
GROUP BY location
```

Differences to your SQL:

We dump the awful old join syntax (`SELECT * FROM a,b WHERE a.id=b.id`) - please always use `a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id`

We join in the status table but we only really do that for the active ones, hence the reason why i stated it as another clause in the ON. I could have put it in a `WHERE`. With an `INNER JOIN` it makes no difference. With an `OUTER JOIN` it can make a big difference, as if you write `a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.id = 'active'` will convert that LEFT JOIN back to an INNER JOIN behaviour unless you made a where clause like `WHERE b.id = 'active' OR b.id IS NULL` - and that's just ugly. If that comparison to a constant had been put in an ON clause, you can skip the `or ... is null` ugliness

We group by location, but we don't necessarily count everything. If we count the result of a `CASE WHEN role = 'Manager' THEN ...`, the case when produces a 1 for a manager, and it produces NULL for a non manager (i didn't specify anything for the else; this is the design behaviour of CASE WHEN in such a scenario). The number didn't have to be a 1 either; it could be `'a'`, `Role`; anything that is non null. COUNT counts anything non null as a 1, and null as a 0. The following are thus equivalent, pick whichever one makes more sense to you:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Role='Employee' THEN 1 END) as count_employees,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Role='Employee' THEN 'a' END) as count_employees,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Role='Employee' THEN role END) as count_employees,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Role='Employee' THEN role ELSE null END) as count_employees,
SUM(CASE WHEN Role='Employee' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count_employees,
```

They both work as counts, but in the SUM case, you really do have to use 1 and 0 if you want the output number to be a count. Actually, 0 is optional, as SUM doesn't sum nulls *(but as mathguy points out below, if you didn't put ELSE 0, then the SUM method would produce a NULLwhen there were 0 items, rather than a 0. Whether this is helpful or hindering to you is a decision for you alone to make)*

I wasn't clear whether managers are employees also. To me, they are, maybe not to you. I added a COUNT(*) that literally counts everyone at the location. Any difference meaning count_employees+count_managers != count_everyone means there was another role, not manager or employee, in the table.. Pick your poison

This `COUNT/SUM(CASE WHEN...)` pattern is really useful for turning data around - a PIVOT operation. It takes a column of data:

```
Manager
Employee
Manager
```

And turns it into two columns, for the count values:

```
Manager Employee
2       1
```

You can extend it as many times as you like. If you have 10 roles, make 10 case whens, and the results will have 10 columns with a grouped up count. The data is pivoted from row-ar representation to column-ar representation

Comment: Very nice explanation! One small thing though (among 30 excellent things) - in the SUM case, you do want to have 0 in the ELSE part. It is true that SUM ignores null; but if all summands are null, the sum will be null, while the COUNT should be 0. (You could use an NVL instead, but why bother.) Or... use COUNT and not SUM, when you need COUNT! :-)

Comment: I agree, hence why I used COUNT, but I sometimes find people look at COUNT as a bit count-erintuitive (if you'll pardon the pun) because the "COUNT coutns anything as 1 and null as 0" isn't widely understood or immediately obvious without explanation, whereas a SUM, can pretty much be deduced as a counting op just by reading it.. Horses for courses and your point about all sums being null -> null is very valid

Comment: Thanks, Caius for this detailed description and a perfect working query!.